# Failed to fetch Components-amd64.yml.xz when Update

Tags: release-loki

I get the latest Elementary OS Loki, buy a new SSD drive for linux. Install Elementary OS there today(03/19) and the this is the first thing I do : `sudo apt-get update`

Here's my result:

`Failed to fetch http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz`

Can someone help me here ? the other thread in this forum claims that the problem had been resolved, which isn't for me.

Comment: Yeah I've got the same problem :(

Comment: did u solved this issue? n how

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by

> sudo apt-get clean
>   sudo apt-get update

the "clean" argument deletes the local repo files.